# Skip Selenium Tests after x amount of time

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing, selenium-webdriver, timeout

I am writing unit tests using selenium in Java. And the problem I am having is that certain tests take longer than usual. I'd like to make it better by adding some sort of timeout or technology that would skip the test if it is taking longer to finish.  Can anyone suggest such technology?

I have found @Timed annotation from Spring framework where it would fail the test if it takes longer than usual but it does not interrupt it or skip the test.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you running your Selenium tests from within JUnit? If so you can use the *timeout* parameter directly on the *@Test* annotation.

From the [documentation](http://junit.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/junit/Test.html):

```
@Test(timeout=100) public void infinity() {
   while(true);
}
```

Comment: the same thing is also applicable for TestNg @Test annotation

Comment: I just noticed my web ui test now opens an extra browser window with "data;" on it. Is this normal?